# Find all elements with specified xpath rather than just the first

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

Currently I have

```
XPATH = "//*[contains(@id, 'id__')]/div[3]/div/div"
elem = driver.find_element("xpath", XPATH)
```

The XPATH uses contains as the id in the xpath is randomized, there is multiple elements with this same structure so it picks the first one it finds and ignores the rest. How can I make it so it grabs every element with this?

Comment: The selenium [docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) can be helpful here.  But `find_elements` should return you a list of matching candidates

Answer (score 0):

```
elem = driver.find_elements("xpath", XPATH)
print(elem[0])
```